# How to launch in system tray icons a MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm developing a MVC application using .NET 6.0. I am publishing the app with the following configuration:
[image]

The app, so far, is launched by double-clicking the .exe, it shows the classic "cmd-style" window.
Now the requirement is to start the portable app minimized into a system tray notification area in Windows (if this is not possible, I was looking for a method to deploy the app as a service which runs in background).
How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What is your deployment/distribution model?

Comment: Hi, I am a beginner so I could have misunderstood your question. If you mean where I want to deploy the app, the idea is that it should be a simple portable MVC app deployed into a Windows PC which acts as a server; this app is then launched automatically after boot (as a simple.exe). So far it remains in the bottom bar (reduced as a icon) but I want to move it to a system tray icon (or run as a background Windows service) to avoid accidental closes by other people (who have access to the same PC).

Comment: I recommend you create a Windows Service project and a Setup project that installs the Windows Service.

Comment: So I have to "convert" my WebApplication MVC project into a Windows Service Project?

Comment: No, you need a separate new project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

To obtain access to the system tray, you need a message pump and a target window.  In other words, a regular command-line executable doesn't cut it.  Basically you need to have an executable that creates a window (can be an invisible one) and then the main thread must pump Windows messages.

I'll say this much for now becuase the provided information is insufficient and explaining all possible scenarios would be too long a response.